# annoying red blocks in neovim

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, plugin-system

im using Neovim from my WSL terminal. I've been exploring the multiple plugins of this amazing open source project and this made me change my `init.vim`, a lot. Now i've messed it up and i don know how to make him 'normal'.

Those are my `init.vim` plugins

:[image]

And those are the changes i've aded to it

[image]

### The problem

now, everytime o try to open a python file, it higlights some redblocks. I want to take them out but i dont know how to do this, here's an example of how my code is right now:

[image]

How can i remove those redblocks? Any help is more than welcome

Note

I know that my `init.vim` is a mess, i also need to discover how can i copy stuff from neovim to clipboard.

Comment: those are trailing whitespaces highlighted as error

Comment: remove both "vim-polyglot"s you have and try again.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble got it, i  don't know how to pase stuff from vim to my clipboard, but when i find out, i'll change the question.

Comment: @Occhima try using the `*` or `+` registers (`"*y`, for example) or disabling the mouse and copying via your terminal emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are trailing whitespaces highlighted as error.

Most probably they are from vim-polyglot plugin:

https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot/blob/4af1321588c7dcb718022226cb27ec325973c2f0/syntax/python.vim#L160

To "fix" it:

1. Either remove those spaces from the file
2. Or add `let g:python_highlight_space_errors = 0` to your config.

Comment: Niice!! Solved it, thank you

Comment: Waitigin for the 6 min so i can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Regarding copy-paste, in Linux adding,
`set clipboard=unnamedplus`

in `init.vim` makes neovim use the system's clipboard.

You could also try,
`set clipboard=unnamed`